# Organizing editable content on mobile

Tags: mobile, data

I am working on altering a mobile UI for a client who needs to be able to add and edit data very efficiently, so in my mind efficiency > design.

My re-design is a lot more efficient than the previous, but I am not happy with the design and am worried users could get lost when scrolling between items.

Each input below is touchable and opens a modal for a user to enter content.

Any ideas to improve design & have a more clear separation between items that have been added?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The add icon on the top main nav, shouldn't there be a 'Done' button instead?
Oh... I think I get it, but this sort of navigation is quite complex and not very straightforward. The tabs for Info and Defects should be separated into individual pages.

Comment: @Ren It auto saves. The add icon is to add a new info or defect item. I agree it's not a great design, but it is efficient, which is top priority. Users of this will be using the app all day every day. Separating info and defects on their own pages isn't ideal since users need to quickly go between the two.

Answer (score 1):

If `each input is touchable and opens a modal for a user to enter content`, it's not necessary the design look like a form. Actually all inputs are buttons, they can look like buttons or just text with the edit icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I really like the button idea.

Answer (score 0):

By 'scrolling between items' items i suppose you mean the different tests. It was my first impression that this could be confusing. If I understand correctly it is the users task is to input those test rather than have an overview over them in detail.

Since a user will only input one test at a time it might not be necessary to have them all in one scrollable view. Also having a modal for each field is not very efficient since the user has to tap on the field, enter the text then close the modal and tap on the next field.

So what I would suggest is to have a list of the tests. A tap on one test opens the whole form for this test. In the modal all fields are editable and the user can jump to the next field using 'Enter' on the keyboard after each field. For the severity I might provide a choice of given severities. Depending on the amount of severities this could be done with a segmented control.

Overview
[image: Overview]

Test detail -form
[image: Form]

As always: test those solutions with actual users. Only this way you will see which solution is the most efficient and usable for your users.

Comment: Thanks, @BrunoH. It is actually currently designed as you suggested, but users are complaining that they need to quickly enter specific content. For example, there could be 5 required items (which means the title is already populated) where a user almost always only wants to enter the description.